# Combinations of word `ticket` according to different rules

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a single regex pattern that would cover all cases of a string 'ticket' combined with a numeric string coming after it. Rules are:

1. `ticket#digit`
2. `ticket #digit`
3. `ticket digit`
4. `ticketdigit`

Sample input:

```
ticket500
ticket 500
ticket#500
ticket #500
Ticket500
Ticket 500
Ticket#500
Ticket #500
```

so far I have `/ticket([\d]+)/i` that correctly reacts for 'ticket500'.

Edit: I am working on large database which has lot's of different variations. I've discovered some other cases not covered by suggested solution. I really need a single regex for PHP to cover all above cases plus the following ones:

```
Ticket # 786
Ticket: # 786
Ticket: #786
Ticket:# 786
Ticket #: 786
Ticket#: 786
Ticket #:786
```

Comment: Try `ticket ?#?\d+` with `i` modifier

Comment: Use `^[Tt]icket ?#?\d+$` https://regex101.com/r/lyRCkq/1

Comment: You are looking for `#` but didn't consider it in your regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This here doesn't accept all combinations with "# " in the middle, and matches the number as `group(1)`:

```
[Tt]icket ?#?([0-9]+)
```

If you don't expect your users to input ticket-numbers in octal notation, you might also want to exclude the zero at the beginning of the number:

```
[Tt]icket ?#?([1-9][0-9]*)
```

**UPDATE**: Another version that matches the updated requirements 2018-02-07, i.e. is more tolerant to spaces and flipped order of colon and sharp:

```
[Tt]icket(?:(?: *:? *#? *)|(?: *#? *:? *))([\d]+)
```

Here it can be seen in action: https://regex101.com/r/itmr0G/2
For case-(in)sensitivity, the same remarks apply: if your environment compiles the pattern as case-insensitive if you append an `/i` to it, then  feel free to do it, if this is the desired behavior.

Comment: This will match `ticket# 20` too which shouldn't.

Comment: This will also match `ticket##20`

Comment: @revo. True. If the sharp-thingies is meant as "number", then " #" is probably a more probable variation than than "# ", indeed.

Comment: @ctwheels That's a much more severe problem. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Actually if you look in rules (question title) you won't look for other variations. I'm going to bring that part into context.

Comment: But it is working fine in my application, so I am accepting this answer. The only modification I made was using case insensitive option after the closing delimiter instead of indicating both cases for only 'T' letter as end-suers could write it in various typos like 'TIcket' and so: `/ticket ?#?([1-9][0-9]*)/i`

Comment: @Nick The longer zero-omitting version seems to work too: https://regexr.com/3kc13 Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Andrey, it's working fine, thanks! Do you know how to cover also cases when end-users might write `ticket: digit`, `ticket:digit`, `ticket: #digit` or `ticket:#digit`?

Comment: @Nick just add an optional colon right after "ticket" part: `[Tt]icket:? ?#?([\d]+)`

Comment: What about cases when end-users mistakenly type `TIcket` or `TICKET` or `TickeT`? Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use the insensitive option `/i` like I suggested yesterday?

Comment: I have also just discovered the case `Ticket # 786` is not covered.

Comment: @Nick "/i" is not part of the regex, it's a flag whether the regex should be compiled as case-insensitive. E.g. in Java, you would have to write `Pattern.compile(Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE, "ticket:? ?#?([\\d]+)")` to achieve the result. Since you didn't specify anything about the language and the standard with which you are working, I have not included any non-standard flags.

Comment: @Nick you have not "discovered" it, you have specified it in your question. And I even got the initial *downvote* for matching the combinations with multiple spaces. If your requirements have changed, feel free to update your question with a more exhaustive list of examples that should or should not match.

Comment: Sorry Andrey. I will accept your answer again, but please read the edited answer again. The language is PHP.

Comment: @Nick I updated it again; Forgot the "or" in the first update-attempt.

Comment: Excellent! Now it works for all the cases found. Hopefully I won't happen on some other crazy combinations. Thanks!

Comment: Well, yeah. But even if that happens, you usually don't simply change an already answered question and mark it as unanswered again. If you solve one problem and then another problem crops up, you ask *another question*.